# Spark DataFrame making column null value to empty

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have joined two data frames with left outer join. Resulting data frame has null values. How do to make them as empty instead of null.

```
| id|quantity|
+---+--------
|  1|    null|
|  2|    null|
|  3|    0.04
```

And here is the schema

```
root
|-- id: integer (nullable = false)
|-- quantity: double (nullable = true)
```

expected output

```
| id|quantity|
+---+--------
|  1|        |
|  2|        |
|  3|    0.04
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make them "empty", since they are double values and empty string `""` is a String. The best you can do is leave them as nulls or set them to 0 using [fill](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) function:

```scala
val df2 = df.na.fill(0.,Seq("quantity"))
```

Otherwise, if you really want to have empty quantities, you should consider changing `quantity` column type to String.